# Issues with Deploying multiple printers in a single GPO with Item-Level Targeting

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, deployment, printer, security-groups

I have a single GPO that contains all printers I need to deploy.
The security filtering for this GPO is set to Authenticated Users.
The GPO is linked to the OU with all of our users.
GPO > User Config > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Printers > (Printer's waiting to be deployed.)

I have a security group that I created with the users I want to have a specific printer. On the common tab of the printer, I check Item-Level Targeting, and target that specific security group. I deploy the printer with the single GPO.

Targeting Sequence:
GPO Editor > ... > Printers > Properties > Common > Check ILT > Targeting... > New Item > Security Group > Select Group > OK

Deploying Sequence:
Print Management > Printer > Deploy with Group Policy... > Select single GPO > Per User > Add > OK

This results in all users in the domain gaining access to this printer. I thought item-level targeting would only limit the deployment to the security group I targeted, but it doesn't. What have I done incorrectly?

I know creating separate GPO's for each printer is a solution, but through research, it seems possible to deploy printers to specific security groups through  a  single GPO. Any tips?

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're deploying it two different ways. If you want to deploy it via Group Policy Preferences using Item Level Targeting than you do not need to and should not deploy it with Group Policy from the Print Management console on your print server.

Comment: Glad to help...